# Store byte[] in a SQLite Database and Select byte[] from SQLite Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, arrays

I have a SQLiteDatabas and I want to store my byte[] in a field called "Data", the Datetype I'm using at this moment is called: Blob and the method to store the Byte array in the SQLiteDatabase looks like this:

```
public bool InsertMessage()
{
    //create string SQl and fill it with the SQLite query for inserting a message.
    string SQL = "Insert into ClockMessages(InsertDateTime, SendDateTime, Data) Values('"+ insertdatetime + "', null, '" + data + "');";
    List<SQLiteParameter> pars = new List<SQLiteParameter>();
    pars.Add(new SQLiteParameter("InsertDateTime", insertdatetime));
    pars.Add(new SQLiteParameter("Data", data));
    //send the SQl query and it's parameters to the SQLiteDatabase class
    return SQLiteDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery(SQL, pars);
}
```

The field Data field in my SQLiteDatabase now contains the following text: System.Byte[]

I want to actually store the real byte[] in the Database, how can I achieve this? Do I need another DateType for the Data field?

Comment: Did you convert an object to the byte-array, or is the byte array your base?

Comment: I didn't convert anything yet, I want to store complete byte array in the SQLite database, but if needed I can cut down the byte array in single bytes and then store them

Comment: It looks as though someone has marked your question answered, but I can't find an example here of how to get the data back out of the database after it has been put in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would convert the byte-array to a base64string and store it in a nvarchar(max) field

Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx

And revert it by byte[] = Convert.FromBase64String

Comment: I'm using SQLite, so I can't use nvarchar(max), should I use the datatype: TEXT ?

Comment: Sorry, haven't seen that - should be ok, hence SQLite is generally unicode and size is not restricted

Comment: When I revert I get the following error: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string. How do you exactly revert?

Answer (score 2):

You should use parameters in the statement:

```
string SQL = "INSERT INTO ClockMessages(InsertDateTime, SendDateTime, Data) VALUES (@InsertDateTime, NULL, @Data)";
```

Everything else seems correct.